# Duplicating and using snapshot in another AWS account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

How can we duplicate and use a snapshot on a different AWS account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either make the snapshot public, or you can add additional user permissions to access the snapshots. You can do this from aws.amazon portal at snapshots section, permission tab, "Add Create Volume Permission:".